# How to not allow cURL in PHP to access local addresses?

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I have setup an online php curl http header retriever.

How it works: a user goes to the url https://www.example.com/header/, then there is an input field where the user can enter a domain name. And click Submit. Then PHP uses curl to retrieve http headers of the website. It retrieves the headers of whatever is entered there, only if the website in valid, if not, it waits for 5 seconds, and closes the connection. If the url is not valid, curl is not performed (PHP uses regex to get that).

But, if the user enters any local address in the input field, it retrieves local address. How can I stop it from retrieving websites from local network? I can't find any question about this.

The cURL options it uses are:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $domain);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 5000);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0);
//Is there any option I could use to not allow local network connection?
```

### Edit

Just in case it is easier if you have the whole code:

```
<form action="" method="get">
<p><b><label for="domain">Domain/IP Address:</label></b> <input type="text" name="url" id="url" value="<?=htmlentities($_GET["url"], ENT_QUOTES);?>"> <input type="submit" class="btn home" value="Lookup"></p>
</form>
<?php
$domain = htmlentities($_GET["url"], ENT_QUOTES);

$ch = curl_init();

// set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $domain);

//return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//enable headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
//get only headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 5000);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0);
// $output contains the output string
$output = htmlentities(curl_exec($ch), ENT_QUOTES);
$curlinfo = curl_getinfo($ch);

// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

if($domain) {
    if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $domain)) { 
          
        // If not exist then add http 
        $domain = "http://" . $domain; 
    } 
    if (filter_var($domain, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
        $result = $output;
        echo "<div id='result'>";
        if (trim($result) != "") {
        echo "<pre style='background-color: #EEEEEE; overflow: auto;'><b>\n" . $result . "\n</b></pre>\n";
        echo "Took ". $curlinfo["total_time"]. "seconds.";
        } else {
            echo "<b>Couldn't fetch website. This might be because the website takes more than 5 seconds to load or because the website does not exist.</b>";
        }
        echo "</div>";
    } else {
        echo "Invalid Domain/IP!";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use [`parse_url`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get the host name from the full URL

```
$host = parse_url( $domain, PHP_URL_HOST );
```

Then use [`gethostbyname`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php) to get the IPv4 address corresponding to the given Internet host name

```
$ip = gethostbyname( $host );
```

Finally check if the ip address falls inside [private network ip ranges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network)

```
// split ip into its components

$ip = explode( '.', $ip );

// check for private addresses

$local_network = ( $ip[0] == 10 ) ||
                 ( $ip[0] == 192 && $ip[1] == 168 ) ||
                 ( $ip[0] == 172 && $ip[1] >= 16 && $ip[1] <= 31 );

if( $local_network )
{
    // manage access to local network...
}
```

Comment: This is vulnerable to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_rebinding

Comment: I think DNS queries are cached for a given minimum time for the same process so if you do this test immediately before using the URL in the same system (or even in the same process), it should be safe.

Comment: This should also test for 169.254.0.0/16 and whole range 172.16.0.0/16 ... 172.31.0.0/16. Yes, IPv4 address space is pretty much insanely fragmented. And `0.0.0.0` should have special handling, too, because it means `localhost` in most implementations. Note that whole `127.0.0.0/8` network is typically localhost, too.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps add a test like `if ($_GET['url'] == "localhost") {//give an error}` before "building" the curl.

Comment: silly me, I took "_user enters "localhost" in the input field_" literally. Is there anything in [`$_SERVER`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server) to compare to (all or part of) `url`?

Comment: Obviously I do not understand what is meant by "localhost" or "local address" in this question. But I do know (and I'm sure you do too)  that if the program needs to perform an action conditionally, it needs to be told that condition. FWIW this "_ If the url is not valid, curl is not performed_" is not true since the curl is executed before `$domain` is checked. That's all I've got.